# How can a range be used in a Vec?

Tags: rust

This code works fine:

```
fn main() {
    let v: i32 = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5].iter().map(|&x: &i32| x.pow(2)).sum();
    println!("{}", v);
}
```

I tried to replace the `vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` with `vec![1..5]` but `iter` and `map` did not work:

```
error[E0631]: type mismatch in closure arguments
 --> src/main.rs:2:36
  |
2 |     let v: i32 = vec![1..5].iter().map(|&x: &i32| x.pow(2)).sum();
  |                                    ^^^ ------------------- found signature of `for<'r> fn(&'r i32) -> _`
  |                                    |
  |                                    expected signature of `fn(&std::ops::Range<{integer}>) -> _`

error[E0599]: no method named `sum` found for type `std::iter::Map<std::slice::Iter<'_, std::ops::Range<{integer}>>, [closure@src/main.rs:2:40: 2:59]>` in the current scope
 --> src/main.rs:2:61
  |
2 |     let v: i32 = vec![1..5].iter().map(|&x: &i32| x.pow(2)).sum();
  |                                                             ^^^
  |
  = note: the method `sum` exists but the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
          `std::iter::Map<std::slice::Iter<'_, std::ops::Range<{integer}>>, [closure@src/main.rs:2:40: 2:59]> : std::iter::Iterator`
          `&mut std::iter::Map<std::slice::Iter<'_, std::ops::Range<{integer}>>, [closure@src/main.rs:2:40: 2:59]> : std::iter::Iterator`
```

I've also [asked this question on the Rust user's forum](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/working-with-range-in-vec/21027?u=hasanoryx).

Comment: Looks like you already got answers on the Forum.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A range like `1..5` is already an iterator, so you do not have to call `iter()` to create one:

```
let v: i32 = (1..5).map(|x: i32| x.pow(2)).sum();
```

Also note that the references are gone because this iterator iterates over values.

If you absolutly need a `Vec`, you need to collect the range into it first:

```
let v: i32 = (1..5)
    .collect::<Vec<i32>>()
    .iter()
    .map(|&x: &i32| x.pow(2))
    .sum();
```

Comment: Your second example can be simplified: `let v: i32 = (1..5).collect::<Vec<i32>>().iter().map(|x| x.pow(2)).sum();`